# powershell pipe will not pass the output until stored in memory

Tags: powershell

when i try to pass crunch generated wordlist to aircrack through the pipe i get OutOfMemoryException.
it seems that crunch output will not be passed to aircrack until crunch finishes generating the entire wordlist which it approximately 102 GB by storing it into memory first.
how can i **FORCE** the output not to be stored in memory to avoid "OutOfMemoryException" and pass the output to aircrack on the fly.
this problem only exists in powershell pipe , i tested this in cmd and bash and i didn't get any problem

```
$Aircrack="D:\PROGRAMME\file\Aircrack-ng.exe"
$AircrackArgs = @('-w-', '-b', 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff','D:\handshakes\MyBSSID.cap')
$crunch="D:\PROGRAMME\file\crunch.exe"
$crunchArgs=@('10', '10', '-t', '%%%%%%%%%%')
&$crunch $CrunchArgs |&$Aircrack $AircrackArgs
```

Comment: Switch to using PowerShell Core (v7+) so that external program outputs unbuffered and output as strings as they are produced. Windows PowerShell (< v5.1) buffers all output first.

Comment: If my assumptions are correct and you are using Windows PowerShell, you will need to construct your own function or something similar to do the required (un)buffering. It won't be a trivial scripting task, which is probably why you don't have a posted answer yet.  I don't think there is a simple knob to turn to get the desired behavior except trying this with PowerShell Core.

Comment: tried powershell v6 and v7 and it works but sadly is very slow,when it should process 1000+ keys in a second, it only process 300 or 200 keys in a second,i have created many powershell functions that helps generating passwords in the hope that everything works ok but eventually i'm forced to give up powershell and converts all my ps functions to bash for better performance